# Create linq Query dynamically

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

i have some problem to create condition inside a linq query (where). the condition inside where is created based on some condition. 
I want to filter a list of Indice based on two property (id_indice_prix, date_indice). i can filter on both of them or only one. do you have any suggestion. 
what i am doing now is that i get all rows from database with linq to entites and then i do if condtion to filter based on condition:

```
   var listeIndiceActualisationPrix = UnitOfWork.Indices_actualisation_prix.ToList();

        if (IdIndicePrix != 0) 
            listeIndiceActualisationPrix = listeIndiceActualisationPrix.Where(x => x.id_indice_prix == IdIndicePrix).ToList();


        if(Annee !=0)
            listeIndiceActualisationPrix = listeIndiceActualisationPrix.Where(x => x.date_indice.Value.Year == Annee).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `.ToList()` every time. When you call `.ToList()`, the query is executed. Build your query dynamically without `.ToList()`, and at the end of your `if` statements, execute `.ToList()` to query the database with the appropriate `WHERE` statements.

Comment: i can't avoid make filter to listeIndiceActualisationPrix  if there is not the first .ToList().

Comment: @ucef What is your error message ? And what is your `UnitOfWork`, is it your `ObjectContext`?

Comment: yes it is the ObjectContext. i didn't have any error, but i want only avoid getting all rows and then make filter based on condition. i want to know if it is posssible to constructthe conditions dynamically at compile time

Comment: @ucef If you do as I mentionned, the database will be queried with the `WHERE` paramaters, and all the rows will not be returned. You can check it with SQL Profiler.

Comment: @ucef Have tried SQL Profiler ? Does my proposition work properly ? Can I help you anymore ?